# How to remove all words occuring before a stop word

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataframe containing platform terms (platform + 3 words before):

| Paper A | Paper B |
| --- | --- |
| at a digital platform | add a digital platform |
| change the consumer platform | got a feedback platform |

For each string in the dataframe I want to delete the stopwords and any word that is occuring in front of the stop word.

Dataframe should look like this:

| Paper A | Paper B |
| --- | --- |
| digital platform | digital platform |
| consumer platform | feedback platform |

My best try so far:

```html
import regex as re
def remove_stops_and_words_before(doc):
            stopwords = re.compile(r"\L<words>", words=['n‘t',  'during', 'from', 'elsewhere', 'herself', 'anyone',...]
            rx_to_last = r'^.*{}'.format(re.escape(stopwords))
            doc = re.sub(rx_to_last, '', doc, flags=re.DOTALL).strip()
            return doc
            
df_new = df.applymap(remove_stops_and_words_before)
```

Comment: `and any word that is occuring in front of the stop word` ... I'm not sure this rule would always play out the way you expect.

Comment: Your code is a mess, do you see you are applying `re.escape` to the compiled regex object, `re.escape(stopwords)`? `^.*{}` means you match any text from start till the *last* occurrence of the stopwords.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have not much experience in programming with python.. "^.*{} means you match any text from start till the last occurrence of the stopwords. " that is exactly what i want to do

Comment: No, what you say is "*I want to delete **the stopwords and any word** that is occuring in front of the stop word.*". That means *a word before the stopword*. Well,  I covered both in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reconsider the way you deal with the word lists and the pattern you use.

Here is a possible solution with the regular `re` package:

```py
# Sample stopwords
stopwords = ['n‘t',  'during', 'from', 'elsewhere', 'herself', 'anyone', 'at', 'a', 'an', 'the']
import re
rx = r"\b(?:\w+\W+)?(?:{})\b".format("|".join(map(re.escape, stopwords)))
# => \b(?:\w+\W+)?(?:n‘t|during|from|elsewhere|herself|anyone|at|a|an|the)\b
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(rx, '', regex=True).str.strip())
# =>               Paper A             Paper B
#    0    digital platform    digital platform
#    1   consumer platform   feedback platform
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gWf5UQ/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary (works if all your stopwords start with a word char, letter/digit/`_`)
- `(?:\w+\W+)?` - an optional sequence of one or more word chars and then one or more non-word chars
- `(?:n‘t|during|from|elsewhere|herself|anyone|at|a|an|the)` - one of the stopwords
- `\b` - a word boundary (works if all your stopwords end with a word char, letter/digit/`_`).

If you really want to remove any text before the last occurrence of a stopword, you'd need

```py
rx = r"(?s).*\b(?:{})\b".format("|".join(map(re.escape, stopwords)))
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you sooo much! You safed my day:)